# how to multiply values in two different interpolation under one ngfor in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

how to multiply values in two different interpolation under one ngfor in angular 7

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of marketArray ">
  <td class="text-center">1</td>
  <td> {{element.price}} </td>
  <td> {{element.quantity}} </td>
  <td>!{{element.price}} * {{element.quantity}}!</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply join both expressions together.

```
{{element.price * element.quantity}}
```

You may refer to the Angular documentation on the usage of [interpolations](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Everything within the `{{}}` is treated as a javascript expression.
Just place the math within the braces.

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of marketArray ">
  <td class="text-center">1</td>
  <td> {{element.price}} </td>
  <td> {{element.quantity}} </td>
  <td>{{element.price * element.quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this.

> {{num1 * num2}}

```js
<tr *ngFor="let element of marketArray ">
  <td class="text-center">1</td>
  <td> {{element.price}} </td>
  <td> {{element.quantity}} </td>
  <td>!{{element.price * element.quantity}}!</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<td><span [innerHtml]="getMultipliedValue(element.price,element.quantity)"></td>
```

or

```
<td>{{getMultipliedValue(element.price,element.quantity)}}</td>
```

TS:

```
  getMultipliedValue(price:number, quantity:number) {
    return price * quantity;
  }
```

Or you can multiply it directly:

```
{{element.price * element.quantity}}
```

Comment: You can even replace `<td><span [innerHtml]="getMultipliedValue(element.price,element.quantity)"></td>` by `<td>{{getMultipliedValue(element.price,element.quantity)}}</td>`